# C# Threading issue & best practices

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my 1st time using threading in an C# Application. Basically its an application which checks a bunch of web sites in a list whether its dead or alive.

Here is my 1st attempt to work with multi-threading

```
    public void StartThread(string URL,int no)
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text += "Thread " + no + " Running" + Environment.NewLine));
            bool b = ping(URL);
            if (b == true) { BeginInvoke(new Action(() => richTextBox2.Text += "Okay" + Environment.NewLine)); }
            else
            { return; }
        });

        newThread.Start();
    }
```

I'm using the above function to create new threads and each thread is created inside a loop.

> foreach (string site in website) {
>       StartThread(site,i);
>       i++; // Counter }

Since i'm a beginner i have few questions.

1. The code works fine but i'm not sure if this the best solution
2. Sometimes threads run perfectly but sometimes Threads does not return any values from the method **ping()** which checks the host and returns true if its online using WebRequest. is it usual ?
3. If i ask the user to specify a no of threads that he needs to use , how can i equally distribute work among those threads ?
4. Is their an elegant way that i track the status of the thread, ( dead / alive ) ? i currently use `rocess.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;`

Comment: Using MessageBox? It will block the UI thread until you dismiss it! An alternative is to log it, or put it into a listview/listbox.

Comment: @David : didn't knew that. Thanks. I added the result to a textbox for now. later on i'll add it to the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your solution is OK. The Thread class has been partially superseded by the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class, if you're writing new code, you can use that. There is also something completely new in .NET 4.5, called [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh300224.aspx) .However, see 4).

2) Your ping method might simply be crashing if the website is dead. You can show us the code of that method.

4)Thread class is nice because you can easily check the thread state, as per your requirements, using the [ThreadState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx) property - just create a `List<Thread>` , put your threads in it, and then start them one by one.

3)If you want to load the number of threads from input and distribute the work evenly, put the tasks in a queue (you can use the ConcurrentQueue that has already been suggested) and have the threads load the URLs from the queue. Sample code:

you initialize everything

```
void initialize(){
ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
foreach(string url in websites)
{
    queue.Enqueue(url);
}
//and the threads
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < threadCountFromTheUser; i++)
{
    threads.Add(new Thread(work));
}}

//work method
void work()
{
    while (!queue.IsEmpty)
    {
        string url;
        bool fetchedUrl = queue.TryDequeue(out url);
        if (fetchedUrl)
            ping(url);
    }
}
```

and then run

```
foreach (Thread t in threads)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

**Code not tested**

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. I'm having trouble initializing **ConcurrentQueue** since it produces an error as soon i initialize it.

the non generic type ThreadTest.form1.ConcurrentQueue cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry , i didn't get you. What are the lines ? If you are referring to declarations , well those should be declared globally right ?..

Else how would other methods read and interact with them if its inside a function ?.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I don't see a problem with your code, where are you getting the error?

Comment: Right here ,`ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();`.

it produces this error : **the non generic type ThreadTest.form1.ConcurrentQueue cannot be used with type arguments.**

Comment: that sounds like you're declaring a type called ConcurrentQueue somewhere else, do you have something like that anywhere?

Comment: Nope. As you saw my code, i've only declare it in the global area once.

Comment: I was using `System.Collections;` so i switched to `System.Collections.Concurrent;` and it works fine.

is their any way to check how manys threads are live/Dead & update Progress ?. Thanks

Comment: See point 4) in my answer for checking thread status. The overall progress can be inferred from the `Count` property of the ConcurrentQueue

Comment: I tried placing queue.Count inside work() function, But how can i get the state of the thread from this ?..

Comment: I also noticed another thing, When i run the loop again after results are displayed, An error occurs saying that threads still exist within the process.  

Is their any elegant way to check the no of threads running and their status and when the job is completed , to abort the threads if running ?

Thank you.

Comment: You get the thread state from the ThreadState property, see 4). The overall progress you can calculate from the total amount of URLs and the length of the queue (the shorter the queue, the more progress you have made). To abort the threads, you can call the Abort() method of the Thread class

Comment: Thank you, yes i'm aware of that but how do i capture each thread in the work() function ? i can do so in the main forloop where threads get created since i can reference to **t** , but inside the work() function ,. ? ...

Answer (score 2):

spinning up a new thread for each request is inefficient ... you probably will want to have a fixed number of worker threads (so one can run on each core of the cpu)

have a look at the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class, which will give you a thread safe first-in-first-out queue where you can enqueue your requests and let each worker thread dequeue a request, process it, and so on until the queue is empty ...

be aware that you may not call controls on your GUI from other threads than the main GUI thread ... have a look at the `ISynchronizeInvoke` Interface which can help you decide if an cross thread situation needs to be handled by invoking another thread

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [the .Net ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).  However, it's generally unsuitable for threads that take more than about second to execute.

See also:
[Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)