# Loop through list and create multple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to loop through a list of URLs and check each URL if the website is down or not using multiple threads.

My approach:

```
            while (_lURLs.Count > 0)
            {
                while (_iRunningThreads < _iNumThreads)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CheckWebsite));                        
                    string strUrl = GetNextURL();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUrl))
                    {
                        t.Start(strUrl);
                        _iRunningThreads++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

    private string GetNextURL()
    {
        lock (_lURLs)
        {
            if (_lURLs.Count > 0)
            {
                string strRetVal = _lURLs[0];
                _lURLs.RemoveAt(0);
                return strRetVal;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

When a thread is finished the `_iRunningThreads` property gets decremented.

My problem is: The outer while loop blocks everything "`while (_lURLs.Count > 0)`".
Adding a `Application.DoEvents()` in the outer while loop helps but I want to use the code in a c# library where `Application.DoEvents()` is not available.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: This operation is, from the outside, a blocking op. Simply run it on a Thread (Backgroundworker) from the main program.

Comment: What is your CheckWebsite method actually doing?  It seems like asynchronous methods would be more suitable than threads for this type of task.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850633/c-sharp-threading-issue-best-practises

Answer (score 3):

Instead of managing the threads yourself, you can use the **[TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)**.
Also, if you're using .Net Framework 4.5 you can even add async/await and the **[WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx)**  method to prevent blocking...

Here is a small example:

```
private async Task CheckUrl()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        string url = GetNextUrl();
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CheckWebSite(url)));
            url = GetNextUrl();
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        // All tasks have finished...

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using the .NET ThreadPool would be a good idea in this case, if the tasks take quite a short time to complete.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx

This allows you to simplify your code a bit as the ThreadPool automatically manages the count of the worker threads. You just have to call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` for each URL you have and increment a running task counter. Queuing items into the `ThreadPool` won't block the UI thread.

Have the ThreadPool tasks decrement the counter (as you have now) and when the counter gets to zero (all tasks have been ran) call a callback function so that your main code knows when all the URLs have been processed. You can update the UI or what ever else you want to do from that callback.